# set the readOnlyRootFilesystem flag to 'true' on the security context of the container's spec

Tags: kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

For containers we are getting vulnerability issue. to fix that we need to enable set the readOnlyRootFilesystem flag to 'true'. But when we enable this flag to true all containers started to fail. Can anyone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 1):

First, understand why, how, and what your applications are writing on the root file system.

If you use a Deployment resource, your application should be stateless (or stateful, if you prefer).
If it needs to write something, prefer to use another resource, like StatefulSet, and mount a Persistent Volume Claim or a Volume to where your POD/Container needs access to write.

If your application needs write access to write logs to a log file, prefer to redirect it to the stdout or add a k8s empty dir (also known as ephemeral storage) and redirect those log files to this empty dir.

docs:

- ephemeral storage: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/
- deployment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/
- statefulsets: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/